# Issue creating tables in JPA

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working an assignment for a class, and am having trouble getting tables to be created in my MySQL database from entities in java. I am trying to get the tables to be created by typing mvn clean install in the project folder in terminal (which is what was given to me as an example to create them once I had the entities in java). No errors or anything occur, and I get a "build successful" message in terminal, but no new tables are created in MySQL. I have confirmed that my endpoint/username/password are all working by setting up the project using jdbc to manually connect instead of JPA and everything works fine that way. Note: This isn't the actual content of the assignment just the initial setup. I've followed the instructions the professor has given multiple times and it is not working. Thanks for the help!

I created my project using the spring command line interface in terminal:
spring init --dependencies=web test

I then added a webapp directory with a index.html file in the src/main directory of the project. Then the project was imported to IntelliJ as a Maven project

I added the following to my application.properties file which is in src/main resources (and is the resources root of the project). The aws endpoint/schema name are also filled in as usual:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://MyAWSEndpoint:3306/SchemaName
spring.datasource.username=MyUsername
spring.datasource.password=MyPassword
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

I then have a class that I created called random which is contained in src/main/java which is my source root for the project.

```
package com.example.test;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class random {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;
  private String name;


  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Additionally I have a Repository I made for the entity in java contained in the same package as the class above.

```
package com.example.test;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface RandomRepository extends CrudRepository<random, Integer> {
}
```

Here is my pom.xml file as well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.45</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Additionally, I have a an application file in src/main/java:

```
package com.example.test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think all that should create tables in MySQL when running mvn install? Your Spring Boot application doesn't *run* when you execute mvn  install. It's only *built*.

Comment: not unless he uses `mvn spring-boot:run`

Comment: In class and in the example provided in the slides to create tables all that was done was mvn clean install to create the tables. Should I be doing mvn spring-boot:run instead?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the below property in the `application.properties` once:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

after the first run you can comment it out again.

To be sure your db user must have the correct privileges to create tables otherwise it won't work :-)

And you need to run the application either by using:

```
mvn clean package && java -jar target/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

or

```
mvn clean spring-boot:run
```

if your application is only build it will not run and not do anything except being compiled and tested.

It might be that your teacher had the setup of the database in the unit tests? then it would have been done...

Good luck

Comment: I just tried this out and it still isn't creating the tables. I think you may be on to something about not having correct privileges though. I created my database on AWS (rds database) and am using the username and password I gave the db when I initially created it. Would this have the correct privileges immediately, or is there something else I should do to upgrade my privilege level?

Comment: Nope I would take a look at the user on aws... see what it may and may not do. It might also be easier to just test it against a mysql in a docker image on your local machine before going to the cloud :-) e.g. https://github.com/IvoNet/ivonet-docker-images/tree/master/databases/mysql

Comment: hmmmm I saw your updated comment, and tried the mvn clean spring-boot:run command. I actually get a build failure when I do this with a laundry list of different errors. The main one that it seems to be highlighting is InvocationTargetException: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0

Comment: Then it seems you have a constructor with an argument in a class that needs something you don't have hehe. Good luck :-)

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the help! I'll probably go to office hours tomorrow to ask the professor about this I guess. I was hoping to get a head start on the assignment but I guess not :(

Comment: oh and your class `random` should be called `Random`